# Adaptive Cards ColumnSets with 2 Input.Text can't set the input to the "id"

Tags: json, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I've been working on a chatbot and i'm using the Microsoft Adaptive Cards for my bot ui.
Currently i am im trying to create a a row that contains 2 textblocks and 2 input.text.

But when entering a value into these input.text they don't seem to set the value to the given id.
This does work however when the input.text are not in a coulmn set but instead are stacked on top of each other.I think its the Azure BotService not handling the JSON right.

I've tried using diffrent channels. Web-Chat, Teams-Chat. It does work on the adaptive card designer but not with any other service. Anyone else got this problem?

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "New TextBlock",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "inputOne",
                            "placeholder": "Placeholder text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "New TextBlock",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "inputTwo",
                            "placeholder": "Placeholder text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue and the pattern which was mentioned in the code block is having some blockage due to some input fields calling structure problem. Try to check the below code block for sample and replace with the current requirements.

**Data JSON:**

```
{
  "title": "Tell us about yourself",
  "body": "We just need a few more details to get you booked for the trip of a lifetime!",
  "disclaimer": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
  "properties": [
    {
      "id": "myName",
      "label": "Your name (Last, First)",
      "validation": "^[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]+$",
      "error": "Please enter your name in the specified format"
    },
    {
      "id": "myEmail",
      "label": "Your email",
      "validation": "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z0-9-]{2,4}$",
      "error": "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    {
      "id": "myTel",
      "label": "Phone Number (xxx-xxx-xxxx)",
      "validation": "^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$",
      "error": "Invalid phone number. Use the specified format: 3 numbers, hyphen, 3 numbers, hyphen and 4 numbers"
    }
  ],
  "thumbnailUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Diver_Silhouette%2C_Great_Barrier_Reef.jpg",
  "thumbnailAlt": "Diver in the Great Barrier Reef"
}
```

**Template JSON:**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "${title}",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "medium",
              "style": "heading"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "${body}",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "${disclaimer}",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "size": "small"
            },
            {
              "type": "Container",
              "$data": "${properties}",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "Input.Text",
                  "label": "${label}",
                  "id": "${id}",
                  "regex": "${validation}",
                  "errorMessage": "${error}",
                  "isRequired": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 1,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "${thumbnailUrl}",
              "altText": "${thumbnailAlt}",
              "size": "auto"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result adaptive card looks like below screen as the sample.

[image]